# LINQ Advance Query 3 Level

Tags: c#, linq

This is My Objects :

Console : Playstation

```
Type : PSX
    Price : 100
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
Type : PS3
    Price : 250
    AvailableIn : []        
Type : PS4      
    Price : 500
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
```

Console : XBOX

```
Type : XBOX 360
    Price : 100
    AvailableIn : []
Type : XBOX One
    Price : 250
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
```

Console : GameBoy

```
Type : GBC
    Price : 100
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
Type : GBA
    Price : 250
    AvailableIn : []
```

---

---

Hi Guys,
I need a LINQ Query to select all available consoles if "AvailableIn" is not null
Here's my expected Result :

Console : Playstation

```
Type : PSX
    Price : 100
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
Type : PS4      
    Price : 500
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
```

Console : XBOX

```
Type : XBOX One
    Price : 250
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
```

Console : GameBoy

```
Type : GBC
    Price : 100
    AvailableIn : [ "USA", "JAPAN" ]
```

Thanks,

I did try

```
var models = Consoles
    .Where(c => c.Types.Any(t => t.AvailableIn.Count() != 0))
```

but It doesn't work for me.

Comment: _"LINQ Advance Query 3 Level"_ What is this?? Consider that the title is used in google to find your question, does this sound like a question that'll help many people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if "AvailableIn" is not null

`null` is not the same as 0, maybe you want:

```
var models = Consoles
    .Where(c => c.Types.Any(t => t.AvailableIn != null && t.AvailableIn.Any()));
```

Comment on other answer:

> I am still getting Type : XBOX 360 Price : 100 AvailableIn : [] and
>   Type : GBA Price : 250 AvailableIn : [] are still in the result, I
>   wanted to get rid of those types if availability = `null`

I guess that you want to exclude all console if any of it's types are not available, is that correct?

Then `All` should work:

```
var models = Consoles
    .Where(c => c.Types.All(t => t.AvailableIn != null && t.AvailableIn.Any()));
```

If you instead want to exclude only the types of all consoles which are not available then you need to create new instances of `Console` without these types:

```
var models = Consoles
    .Where(c => c.Types.Any(t => t.AvailableIn != null && t.AvailableIn.Any()))
    .Select(c => new Console
    {
        AvailableIn = c.Types
                       .Where(t => t.AvailableIn != null && t.AvailableIn.Any()),
        OtherProperties ....
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var models = Consoles.Where(x=>x.Types.Any(t=>t.AvailableIn.Any()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @jyparask,
with this linq query, xbox360 and GBA are still appearing of the result. I wanted to get rid if them, if they are not available